# Redshift Scheduled Query Error Notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-redshift, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I am using Redshift scheduled queries to run an UNLOAD command. I would like to receive a notification if the query fails. I enabled SNS, but the message is the same regardless of if the job succeeds of fails. How can I receive a notification only if the job fails?

Update:
I am able to get a response with the error message using the below command. How do I set up CloudWatch or some other service to monitor for this and send a notification?

`aws redshift-data describe-statement --id {id} --region us-west-2`

Comment: Your command use `--id {id}` so how can you fetch all scheduled queries `id`s to check all its status?

Comment: Was a solution ever found here? If I try to use describe-statement with the id that is show in AWS console, it tells me the query doesn't exist.

I've looked at the SNS notifications as well as EventBridge rules which seem to drive the Redshift scheduled queries, and neither seem to provide any indication that there is a failure.

It's pretty absurd that AWS doesn't have a formal solution around this. I am considering moving scheduled queries to Lambda instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to go:

- You can use a lambda function with boto3 to check if the queries on redshift ran succesfully
- You can also use a lambda function to check the logs in cloudwatch

Comment: What do you use with boto3? Redshfit does not record failed query execution and you cannot fetch the schedule hisotry neither.

Comment: What do you check in CloudWatch? I guess Redshfit does not record query execution in CloudWatch

Comment: ooh i should have given more details.

Comment: you can query the history of your queries and you can also tag your queries, and then just find the labeled queries

Comment: How can you query the history of your queries? `STL_QUERY` table does not record failed query and `redshift-data.list-statements` api only returns query executed via `redshift-data.execute-statement`.

Comment: STL_QUERY tells you when a query was aborted by any means

Comment: STL_QUERY does not record failed query, make the test: `select * from inexistant_table` then `select * from stl_query  where querytxt like '%inexistant_table%'`, you wont find the failed query.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the AWS Eventbridge Rule. Create a rule with the following pattern:

```
{ "source": [ "aws.redshift-data" ], "detail-type": [ "Redshift Data Statement Status Change" ], "detail": { "state": [ "FAILED" ] } }
```

This rule will be triggered whenever a scheduled query fails. You can set the target of this rule as an SNS topic which can forward the event payload to your email. Here is the sample payload you can expect in case a scheduled query fails:

> {"version":"0","id":"64207b01-e97e-b05a-c090-1ba0c3eee01f","detail-type":"Redshift
> Data Statement Status
> Change","source":"aws.redshift-data","account":"xxxxxx","time":"2023-04-13T11:04:38Z","region":"eu-central-1","resources":["arn:aws:redshift:eu-central-1:xxxxxx:cluster:xxxx-cluster"],"detail":{"principal":"arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/RedshiftScheduler/xxxxx","statementName":"xxxxx","statementId":"65ecdd43-5c0e-4507-841d-5857c6835b1f","redshiftQueryId":1.6043919E7,"state":"FAILED","rows":-1.0,"expireAt":1.681642837E9}}

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A solution we implemented in a python lambda function:

1. Listing all EventBridge rules: `aws events list-rules`.
2. For each rule get the targets and filter on those having a Redshift cluster target: `aws events list-targets-by-rule`
3. For each Redshfit target, try to find it in  `STL_QUERY` by matching the SQL statement and CRON definition with the columns `querytxt` and `starttime`. You can use [pyawscron](https://pypi.org/project/pyawscron/) to convert your CRON to a timestamp.
4. Raise an alert if the record does not exist.

This solution can be easily enhanced according to your needs.

Tips to facilitate the lookup in `STL_QUERY`: use a specific `user` for your scheduled queries.

Hope it can helps.